# How to set expired time inside shared preferences in Flutter

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I have data inside shared preferences... but I want to remove that data after 23:59:59 have passed... is there a way how to do that or is there a way so that my data will get expired at 23:59:59

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new shared preference to store the date the shared preference of your data is saved. Then every time the app is launched you can run a function that tests whether the stored date plus 23:59:59 less today's date is <= 0 if so delete the shared preference. Compare it with today's date.

You can accomplish this by using the following functions as an example to run your calculations:

millisecondsSinceEpoch()

and DateTime today = DateTime.now();
DateTime hoursLater = today.add(Duration(hours: 24));